# Scheduling of Multiple Threads using Mutex and Condition Variable

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, condition-variable

I'm trying to create four threads printing some message.
I'm facing some issue with synchronisation.

Here is what my `main()` looks like

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;    
pthread_cond_t  cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; 
int count = 4;

int main (void)
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4;
    pthread_create (&thread4, NULL, function4, NULL);
    pthread_create (&thread3, NULL, function3, NULL);
    pthread_create (&thread2, NULL, function2, NULL);
    pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, function1, NULL);

    pthread_join (thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join (thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join (thread3, NULL);
    pthread_join (thread4, NULL);
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

`function1()` prints `Function 1`, `function2()` prints `Function 2` and so on.

Desired Output should be the following:

```
Function 1   
Function 2  
Function 3  
Function 4
```

Actual Output:

```
Function 1
/* Infinitely runs (Deadlock maybe) */
```

**Actual Question**:
Can we use one single condition variable for Synchronization of two or more threads ? If so how ?

If not, how do I tackle this problem ?

---

Here is the definition of `function(n)`

```
void *function1 ()
{
    while (1)
    {
    if (count == 4)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
            printf("Function 1\n");
            count --;
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
            pthread_cond_signal (&cond);
            return NULL;
        }
      else
          pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

---

```
void *function2 ()
{
while (1)
    {
        if (count == 3)                                                         
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
            printf("Function 2\n");
            count--;
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
            pthread_cond_signal (&cond);                                        
            return NULL;
        }
        else                                                                    
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);        
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

---

```
void *function3 ()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if(count == 2)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
            printf("Function 3\n");
            count--;
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
            pthread_cond_signal (&cond);
            return NULL;
        }
        else
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);      
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

---

```
void *function4 ()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if(count == 1)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
            printf("Function 4\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
            pthread_cond_signal (&cond);
            return NULL;
        }
        else
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please note that you're supposed to use `pthread_cond_wait` while holding a lock on the mutex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a more clear understanding, I have resolved this issue.
This is a case of race condition.

Things wrong with the code:

1. Use `pthread_cond_broadcast` instead of`pthread_cond_signal`.
   From the `man` pages

   > The `pthread_cond_broadcast()` function shall unblock all threads currently blocked on the specified condition variable cond.
   >
   > The `pthread_cond_signal()` function shall unblock at least one of the threads that are blocked on the specified condition variable cond
2. Not acquiring a `lock` before checking for `if (count == X)`, Need a
       place a lock before that (since `count` is global/shared variable).
3. Not placing an `unlock` if the control goes to `else`. Since a lock
   is already placed (earlier before `else`), you need to `unlock`
   it.

   If you fail to do so, other threads will try to `lock` a mutex,
   that is already locked , leading to race conditions.

---

Function should be as follow

```
void *function1 ()
{
    while (1)
    {
        /* Take a lock on the Mutex */
        pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
        if (4 == count)
        {
            printf("Function 1\n");    /* Perform your task */
            count--;
            /* Once operation on shared variable (count) is completed, release lock*/
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);

            /* Broadcast to other threads about completion of task */
            pthread_cond_broadcast (&cond);
            return NULL;
        }
        else 
        { 
            /* If count doesnt match, wait on the condition (wait for signal from other threads) */
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);   
            /* Unlock the mutex, since it was locked earlier - else goes to deadlock */
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

---

[Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11855565/) is the complete working code.

Answer (score 0):

The change required is simple:

instead of:

```
else
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
```

do this:

```
else {
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
}
```

It works for me with these changes, but results in unpredictable behaviour without the changes.

Edit:

This above mentioned simple way still leaves a race condition and doesn't fix the `signal` vs `broadcast` problem. To avoid it, the code should be structured like the following:

```
pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
if (count == 4)
{
    printf("Function 1\n");
    count --;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
    pthread_cond_broadcast (&cond); // NOTE: broadcast, not signal!
    return NULL;
 }
else
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
```

Note that `pthread_cond_broadcast` is necessary as you want to wake up all threads.

Comment: The above changes are giving me the same results, no change.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Note the last edit. It fixes the race condition and uses broadcast instead of signal which is really necessary in this use case. I managed to reproduce the problem occasionally and now it always works for me.

Comment: Thanks you, I can see the prints from `function1` & `function2` only, not the rest of them. Here is the exact code I'm using http://paste.ubuntu.com/10683407/ . I will look into `pthread_cond_broadcast` in parallel.